# Break function not working in Python 3.5! i dont know why. i need advise

Tags: python, break

Ok, so i tryed making a number guessing game...didnt work so i turned to youtube.
i even tryed COPYING somone elses code! still didnt work for me. this is my code.

```
import random
import time

print('This is a guessing gamefrom 1-1000.')

num = random.randint(1, 1000)

time = time.time()

guess = int(input('what number do you guess? '))

playing = True

while(playing):
    if guess < num:
        print('Guess is too low!')
    elif guess > num:
        print('Guess is too High!')
    elif guess == num:
        break

print('Nice job!')

time2 = time.time()

totalTime = str(int(time2-time1))

print('you took ' + totalTime + 'seconds to guess the number')
```

and if i run it and enter a number it repeats either "answer is too high" or "answer is too low" i dont know what to do.

Comment: You are not asking for a new guess after the initial one. Move `guess` assignment below `while(playing):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't ask for a new guess, you will either get it right on the first try and break out of the loop, or you will loop forever because that wrong `guess` will be the same on every iteration. To fix this, reassign `guess` every time in your while loop:

```
time = time.time()

playing = True

while(playing):
    guess = int(input('what number do you guess? '))
    if guess < num:
        # etc.
```

Comment: thx man! im a noob to coding if you couldent tell :P but i think its pretty fun